# Adding items to an outer collection from within a ForEachAsync, implicity captured closure

Tags: c#, async-await

First off, I know enough about asynchronous operations to be dangerous, as they say.  Resharper is giving me a warning with the code below that I have an implicitly captured closure for the "response" object at ForEachAsync.  I understand why it's warning me, but I'm not sure if there is anything particular wrong with my implementation (this does work by the way) or if there is a more appropriate way to populate the "orders" collection from within the ForEachAsync.

```
  public async Task<Response<IEnumerable<Order>>> HandleGetOrdersAsync(GetAllOrdersQuery query)
  {
     Expression<Func<Order, bool>> dateTimeFilter = order =>
        order.OrderTime >= query.StartDateTime &&
        order.OrderTime <= query.EndDateTime;

     Expression<Func<order, bool>> isActiveFilter = order =>
        !query.IsComplete ||
        order.OrderStatus == OrderStatusName.Complete;

     var items = _ctx.orders
        .Include(c => c.Customers)
        .Include(p => p.Payments)
        .Where(dateTimeFilter)
        .Where(isActiveFilter)
        .OrderBy(n => n.OrderNo)
        .Skip(query.PageSize * query.Page)
        .Take(query.PageSize)
        .Select(o => o);

     // ... items count to be performed here ...

     var response = new Response<IEnumerable<Order>>();
     var orders = new List<Order>();

     await items.ForEachAsync(i =>
     {
        var order = new Order
        {
           ResultNo = i.OrderNo,
           CustomerName = i.Customer.Name,
           PaymentType = i.Payment.Type
        };

        orders.Add(order);

     }).ContinueWith(t =>
     {
        response = new Response<IEnumerable<Order>>(orders);
     });

     return response;
  }
```

Comment: Why in the world do you have a `ContinueWith` in your code?  Just `await` the `Task` and use the result it resolves to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work as you have noticed but the delegate will keep the `orders` variable alive since it has a reference to it and consequently your class will not be able to be collected by the GC as long as the delegate is not eligible for garbage collection.

```
 var orders = new List<Order>();

 await items.ForEachAsync(i =>
 {
    var order = new Order
    {
       ResultNo = i.OrderNo,
       CustomerName = i.Customer.Name,
       PaymentType = i.Payment.Type
    };

    orders.Add(order);

 }).ContinueWith(t =>
 {
    response = new Response<IEnumerable<Order>>(orders);
 });
```

**What if `orders` is a value type such as int?**

In this case it does not apply, but if `orders` was an integer and there was no `await` and the code continued after the delegate which is capturing the `orders` variable, and you modify variable after the delegate, and the delegate is invoked at a later time (think event handlers) it will use the modified copy. Why? Because event though it is an integer, the reference is captured.

I guess Resharper is just warning you and you need to make the decision whether it will cause issues in your case. All it can do is warn you because in some cases it can cause issues while in other cases it will not cause any issues.